# List recursive with checkbox component data into parent component update values

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, inertiajs

Help to list recursive with checkbox component data into parent component update values:

Parent File:

```
<TreeVue :items="props.allModules" :selectedItems="userForm.userModules"/>
```

TreeVue File:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.name" class="overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-gray-50">
        <div class="px-4 py-5 sm:p-6" >
            <div class="flex items-center ">
                <input :id="item.id" type="checkbox" :value="item.id" v-model="props.selectedItems" class="w-6 h-6 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 rounded border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600">
                <label for="default-checkbox" class="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">{{ item.name  }}</label>
            </div>
            <div v-if="item.children" class="ml-5">
                <Tree :items="item.children" :selectedItems="selectedItems" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { defineProps } from "vue";

    const props = defineProps({
        items: Object,
        selectedItems: Object,
    });
</script>
```

ConsoleLog:

```
app.js:7839 [Vue warn] Set operation on key "selectedItems" failed: target is readonly. Proxy {items: Proxy, selectedItems: Proxy}
```

I need to update parent value after selected item on child TreeVue.

I read something about Emit, but I don't know how to implement it, because I'm new to Vue.

Comment: Here are the Docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#component-events